# android expandable list need help

Tags: android, position, expandablelistview

```
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onChildClick: " + childPosition);

    Button btnPlay=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Play);
    Button btnDelete=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Delete);
    Button btnEmail=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Email);
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(FindFilesByType.this, "u clicked play btn", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               
        }
    });
```

```
in to above code i've made expandable list into that first i've put some content and if it expand,it displays 3 button.. 

PLAY,EMAIL and DELETE
my problem is that it doesn't react on button click event
what is i am missing?
thank in advance -pragna
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think, You should implement `onClick` of `Button` while overriding the `getChildView()`

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                   View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(FindFilesByType.this).inflate(R.layout.row, null) ; //we assume your layout file name is row.xml
        Button btnPlay=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Play);
        Button btnDelete=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Delete);
        Button btnEmail=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Email);
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(FindFilesByType.this, "u clicked play btn", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               
            }
        }); 
        return v;


}
```

Comment: So what is the problem you faced...? Does the `Toast` shown up..?

Comment: no it doesn't show mw.. and u said view..what can i pass over there?

Comment: what is your row layout xml name. suppose if it is row.xml and it uses `LinearLayout` as root container. so you will get your `View` or `LinearLayout` as `LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row, null) ;`

Comment: aaahhhh, I forgot to add return statement as `return v;` and also i've edited the answer.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

Comment: <TextView android:id="@+id/childname"
         android:paddingLeft="50px"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:textSize="14px"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/rgb"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:textSize="14px"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

Comment: <Button android:id="@+id/Play"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:text="Play song"
                    />  </LinearLayout>

Comment: above is my XML file what should i do?

Comment: i've tried your edited code thanks but.. stil.. not working for me :(

Comment: could you post all your adapter class